# performing sparql query on the rdf data stored in relational database

Tags: sparql, flask-sqlalchemy, rdflib

I have stored large amount of RDF data into a relational database with the help of rdflib_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.Now I want to execute Sparql query over the same.I can not find any thing to know how to implement sparql query here.
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Including sample code would make it easier to know what you are after but see the [documentation](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html) on querying an RDFLib graph with SPARQL.

Using the example from the rdflib-sqlalchemy [README](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-sqlalchemy) where graph is the name of the open graph.

```py
rq = "select ?s where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10"

results = graph.query(rq)
for row in results:
    print row.s
```